# How can I hide my App tag on a post I created on facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created a facebook app from which anyone can post to his wall or his friend's wall. But at that post at the bottom the post it displays the app hyperlink. But want to remove it so that it should look like the user create it himself and not by my app.

Is there any way to do so. I use faecbook graph api with Javascript sdk.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

First: Posting to the wall of a friend is highly spammy and should be avoided as much as possible. With the PHP SDK it´s not even possible anymore afaik, or will be removed very soon because it is deprecated. The only way is to use the FB.ui feed dialog of the JavaScript SDK:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

That being said, there is no way to remove the App Link. Postings made through an App always have to be easily identifiable. It may be possible that posting via the PHP SDK does not show the App Link, but as i said: that function is deprecated for spam reasons and should not be used anymore.

Comment: I knew it. But I see one website can do this,I don't know how they do it. Here it is

http://birthdayfb.com/

Comment: my god, i hate those birthday spam apps...lol...anyway, i don´t want to test it with my account, but i can tell you that the app uses the php sdk for sure. and with that, it will not be possible to post to the wall of a friend sooner or later. that function is deprecated and will be removed very soon.